# displaying data in ul and li list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am facing an issue in displaying my news data in a ul and li list. the code is:

```
$('#NewsPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){ 
    Newslist = "";
    $.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){ 
        Newslist += "<li><a href='#'>" + v.news_title + "</a></li>"; 
    }); 
    $("ul#displayNews").html(Newslist); 
});
```

in my html file i have:

```
<div data-role="content"> 
<div id="displayNews"> 
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"> </ul> 
</div> 
</div>
```

note that Newslist is a global variable i defined in a file called gv_file.js and included in the head of html file

Comment: please note that i had to add spaces before and after li to be displayed correctly in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isn't correct. `ul#displayNews` looks for `<ul id="displayNews">`, not a `ul` contained within `#displayNews`.

Try this (with a little `.append` goodness for convenience):

```
$('#NewsPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){ 
    $.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){ 
        $('#displayNews ul').append('<li><a href="#">' + v.news_title + '</a></li>'; 
    }); 
});
```

Or better yet, use the more modern `on()` instead of `live()` (requires jQuery 1.7 or greater):

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#NewsPage', function(event, ui){ 
    $.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){ 
        $('#displayNews ul').append('<li><a href="#">' + v.news_title + '</a></li>'; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks mblase75 for your reply. I tried the .append but still the data is not displayed :s

Comment: firebug is saying that $(document).on is not a function

Comment: I forgot to mention that `$(document).on` requires jQuery 1.7 or greater.

Comment: aha i c. m running jquery 1.6. however using '#displayNews ul' has solved my issue but the data is not displayed correctly. i have 2 rows fetched in json to be displayed in li but these 2 rows are being displayed in one li only. here is the code:

$('#NewsPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
 var Newslist;
 Newslist = "";
 $.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){
  Newslist += "<li>";
  Newslist += v.news_title;
  Newslist += "</li>";
  });
 $("#displayNews ul").append(Newslist);
 });

Comment: That code should work fine. I suggest using your browser's debugger to see what the browser is seeing, or posting a new question with your new issue.

Comment: hi mblase75. Thanks for ur support. I have put static data in the html file inside ul. I have checked the browser data using firebug and found that jquerymobile is adding class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c" inside each li which is not the case if i build the li dynamically. Please advise.

Comment: So you're using jQuery-UI with this?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content"> 
  <div id="displayNews"> 
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"> </ul> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#NewsPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){ 
    Newslist = "";
    $.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){ 
        Newslist += "<li><a href='#'>" + v.news_title + "</a></li>"; 
    }); 
    $("#displayNews ul").html(Newslist).listview("refresh"); 
});
```